# Build OpenVPN with custom OpenSSL

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, openssl, openvpn

I'm trying to build openvpn-2.3.4 with the latest openssl-1.0.1h. I compiled openssl from sources  /usr/openssl-1.0.1h with `--prefix=/opt/custom-openssl`. Then I configured openvpn sources with next line:

`./configure --prefix=/opt/custom-openvpn OPENSSL_SSL_LIBS="-L/usr/openssl-1.0.1h/" OPENSSL_SSL_CFLAGS="-I/usr/openssl-1.0.1h/include/openssl/" OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBS="-L/usr/openssl-1.0.1h/" OPENSSL_CRYPTO_CFLAGS="-I/usr/openssl-1.0.1h/include/openssl/"`

Both `make` and `make install` passed with no errors but when I check versions I get

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1h Jun 5 2014 // <-------
openvpn --version
OpenVPN 2.3.4 Jun 4 2014
OpenSSL version 1.0.1f Jan 6 2014 // <------
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are probably loading Ubuntu's version of the shared object at runtime. Try setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for `openvpn`. Or, recompile OpenVPN and set an `rpath`. Or, recompile OpenVPN but use the static version of the OpenSSL libraries.

Comment: +jww you are right, it used Ubuntu's version. I completly removed openssl from machine and then got some errors. The fixed version in my own answer below

Comment: Also see [How do I clear Bash's cache of paths to executables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5609/56041), [Does Bash have cache of executables?](https://superuser.com/q/871854/173513) and [How to 'hash -r' and refresh all shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/398028/56041)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was that compiler used Ubuntu's version of the shared object. The reason was some errors in commands above. So, final version of my configure:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/custom-openvpn OPENSSL_SSL_LIBS="-L/usr/openssl-1.0.1h/ -lssl" OPENSSL_SSL_CFLAGS="-I/usr/openssl-1.0.1h/include/" OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBS="-L/usr/openssl-1.0.1h/ -lcrypto" OPENSSL_CRYPTO_CFLAGS="-I/usr/openssl-1.0.1h/include/"
```

Thanks to jww and http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.network.openvpn.user/34824

Comment: This answer seems to be outdated/broken now. I followed the suggestion in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39006247/474189 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/openvpn-2.3.6 PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR="/opt/openssl-1.0.2/lib/pkgconfig/"
```

-- make output snnipet

```
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../../include -I../../src/compat    -I/opt/openssl-1.0.2/include   -I/opt/openssl-1.0.2/include      -g -O2 -MT base64.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/base64.Tpo -c -o base64.o base64.c
mv -f .deps/base64.Tpo .deps/base64.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../../include -I../../src/compat    -I/opt/openssl-1.0.2/include   -I/opt/openssl-1.0.2/include      -g -O2 -MT buffer.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/buffer.Tpo -c -o buffer.o buffer.c
mv -f .deps/buffer.Tpo .deps/buffer.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../../include -I../../src/compat    -I/opt/openssl-1.0.2/include   -I/opt/openssl-1.0.2/include      -g -O2 -MT clinat.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/clinat.Tpo -c -o clinat.o clinat.c
```

OpenVPN start output:

```
$ sudo /opt/openvpn-2.3.6/sbin/openvpn --config server-no-auth.conf 
Wed Feb  4 09:40:23 2015 OpenVPN 2.3.6 x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [MH] [IPv6] built on Feb  4 2015
Wed Feb  4 09:40:23 2015 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2 22 Jan 2015, LZO 2.08
Wed Feb  4 09:40:23 2015 ******* WARNING *******: all encryption and authentication features disabled -- all data will be tunnelled as cleartext
Wed Feb  4 09:40:23 2015 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Wed Feb  4 09:40:23 2015 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Wed Feb  4 09:40:23 2015 /sbin/ifconfig tun0 172.16.1.1 pointopoint 172.16.1.2 mtu 1500
Wed Feb  4 09:40:23 2015 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]
Wed Feb  4 09:40:23 2015 UDPv4 link remote: [undef]
```