# Failed openssl check in ./configure

Tags: openssl, openvpn, kali-linux

I am trying to manually install openvpn 2.4.8 on my kali 2020.1, and it shows

```
configure: error: openssl check failed
```

I looked at many threads such as [this](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=26507) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38985889/build-openvpn-with-specific-openssl-version), but couldn't fix it.
What is the reason and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Short version : libssl-dev library is missing which can be fixed by running

```
apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Install OpenVPN 2.4.7
Visit https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/
Download via
#wget https://swupdate.openvpn.org/community/releases/openvpn-2.4.7.tar.gz
#tar xfz openvpn-2.4.7.tar.gz
#cd openvpn-2.4.7
#./configure
Output:
checking for a BSD-compatible install… /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane… ye
schecking for a thread-safe mkdir -p… /bin/mkdir
.
.
[truncated output]
.
checking for SSL_CTX_new… no
configure: error: openssl check failed
Install OpenSSL
Visit https://www.openssl.org/source
Download via
#wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2s.tar.gz
#tar xvf openssl-1.0.2.tar.gz
#./config -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-rpath,'$(LIBRPATH)'
#make
#make install
Output:
#bash: /usr/bin/openssl: No such file or directory
Run Commands:

#ln -s /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl

#ln -s /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl /usr/local/bin/openssl

Note:
-openssl may or may not be needed. Since I uninstalled openssl to install latest version. Steps are mentioned below.
-/usr/local/bin is for locally compiled package and /usr/bin is for trivial binaries not needed in single user mode
Try Installing OpenVPN
#./configure 
#make
#make install
#openvpn — version
Output:
#OpenVPN 2.4.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jul 26 2019library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g 1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08Originally developed by James YonanCopyright © 2002–2018 OpenVPN Inc <sales@openvpn.net>
For the error “configure: error: ssl is required but missing”
#apt-get install libssl-dev
For the error “configure: error: lzo enabled but missing”
#apt-get install liblzo2-de
For the error “configure: error: libpam required but missing “
#apt-get install libpam0g-dev
Note:
-Sudo is not used as the vm was running as root. Also we can specify manually where to install ssl libraries,etc. It is just a general workaround.
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please edit your post to include an explanation of the code and how it helps solve the problem in the question.